# In python how to read a url content that uses the current windows default authentication?

Tags: python, pandas, powerbi

I have a URL of a power Bi report that I wish to read from it using python.
the report opens normally in any browser since I'm logged into windows 10 using my username that has access to that URL. (default authentication)

I tried this code but it doesn't seem to understand that I'm logged in.
how can I read the URL using my windows default authentication?

```
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd

f=open("link.txt","r")
url=f.readline()

#create a password manager with defaule credentials.
password_mgr = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
password_mgr.add_password(None,url,None,None)

#create an authentication handler with the password manager
auth_handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)

#create an opener with the authentication handler
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(auth_handler)

#open the url with the opener
response = opener.open(url)

#read the contents
content = response.read()


print(content.decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `HTTPBasicAuthHandler`, which requires providing a username and password, you can use `HTTPNtlmAuthHandler` from the `ntlm-auth` library to authenticate with Windows default authentication. Here's how to modify your code:

```py
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
from ntlm.auth import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler

f = open("link.txt", "r")
url = f.readline()

# create an authentication handler with the default NTLM authentication
auth_handler = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler()

# create an opener with the authentication handler
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(auth_handler)

# open the url with the opener
response = opener.open(url)

# read the contents
content = response.read()

print(content.decode("utf-8"))
```

This should allow you to read the URL content using your Windows default authentication. Note that you need to install the `ntlm-auth` library for this to work.

Comment: installed ntlm-auth but i get the error "from ntlm.auth import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ntlm'"